# Regex taking too many characters

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need some help with building up my regex.

What I am trying to do is match a specific part of text with unpredictable parts in between the fixed words. An example is the sentence one gets when replying to an email:

On *date* at *time* person *name* has written:

**The cursive parts are variable, might contains spaces or a new line might start from this point.**

To get this, I built up my regex as such: On[\s\S]+?at[\s\S]+?person[\s\S]+?has written:

Basically, the [\s\S]+? is supposed to fill in any letter, number, space or break/new line as I am unable to predict what could be between the fixed words tha I am sure will always be there.

Now comes the hard part, when I would add the word "On" somewhere in the text above the sentence that I want to match, the regex now matches a much bigger text than I want. This is due to the use of [\s\S]+.

How am I able to make my regex match as less characters as possible? Using "?" before the "+" to make it lazy does not help.

Example is here with words "From - This - Point - Everything:". Cases are ignored.

Correct: https://regexr.com/3jdek. 
Wrong because of added "From": https://regexr.com/3jdfc

The regex is to be used in VB.NET

A more real life, with html tags, can be found here. Here, I avoided using [\s\S]+? or (.+)?(\r)?(\n)?(.+?)

Correct: https://regexr.com/3jdd1

Wrong: https://regexr.com/3jdfu after adding certain parts of the regex in the text above. Although, in html, barely possible to occur as the user would never write the matching tag himself, I do want to make sure my regex is correctjust in case

These things are certain: I know with what the part of text starts, no matter where in respect to the entire text, I know with what the part of text ends, and there are specific fixed words that might make the regex more reliable, but they can be ommitted. Any text below the searched part is also allowed to be matched, but no text above may be matched at all

Another example where it goes wrong: https://regexr.com/3jdli. Basically, I have less to go with in this text, so the regex has less tokens to work with. Adding just the first < already makes the regex take too much.

From my own experience, most problems are avoided when making sure I do not use any [\s\S]+? before I did a (\r)?(\n)? first

Answer (score 0):

`[\s\S]` matches all character because of union of two complementary sets, it is like `.` with special option `/s` (dot matches newlines). and regex are greedy by default so the largest match will be returned.

Following *correct* link, the token just after the shortest match must be `geschreven`, so another way to write without using lazy expansion, which is more flexible is to prepend the repeated chracter set by a negative lookahead inside loop,

so

```
<blockquote type="cite" [^>]+?>[^O]+?Op[^h]+?heeft(.+?(?=geschreven))geschreven:
```

becomes

```
<blockquote type="cite" [^>]+?>[^O]+?Op[^h]+?heeft((?:(?!geschreven).)+)geschreven:
```

- `(?: )` is for non capturing the group which just encapsulates the negative lookahead and the `.` (which can be replaced by `[\s\S]`)
- `(?! )` inside is the negative lookahead which ensures current position before next character is not the beginning of end token.

Following comments it can be explicitly mentioned what should not appear in repeating sequence :

```
From(?:(?!this)[\s\S])+this(?:(?!point)[\s\S])+point(?:(?!everything)[\s\S])+everything:
```

or

```
From(?:(?!From|this)[\s\S])+this(?:(?!point)[\s\S])+point(?:(?!everything)[\s\S])+everything:
```

or

```
From(?:(?!From|this)[\s\S])+this(?:(?!this|point)[\s\S])+point(?:(?!everything)[\s\S])+everything:
```

to understand what the technic `(?:(?!tokens)[\s\S])+` does.

- in the first `this` can't appear between `From` and `this`
- in the second `From` or `this` can't appear between `From` and `this`
- in the third `this` or `point` can't appear between `this` and `point`
  etc.

Comment: I am aware. Thats why my regexes aren't reliable enough. I need a replacement that can also track new lines which returns me a match with the fewest.

Comment: ok haven't read all question, correct answer depends on match just after `[\s\S]+` and backtracking strategy, for example your _correct_ link let's me think the token must be `geschreven` and after there is a `:`, i will update my answer following new understanding

Comment: basically, the token can be anything. There might be a `:`or a `>`, there might be nothing, but mostily there is. 
What always is the same is a specific first token, a specific ending token, and possible fixed tokens in between. The first, ending and other tokens are filled in with random letters, symbols, spaces or line breaks.

Comment: Just tried the regex out and I didn't change anything in the faulty link. It still takes too much characters

Comment: ok i understand now the faulty link it matches to much because starts to early the matching bprocess is left to right, what should be correct match for the first link ?

Comment: is `From(?:(?!From|this)[\s\S])+this(?:(?!point)[\s\S])+point(?:(?!everything)[\s\S])+everything:` ok ?

Comment: Does not work. It won't take too much when the user writes From, but it does the moment the user writes From, and somewhere further down the line, writes this. As in: https://regexr.com/3jdlu. Correct match should be like it is in correct link, when the user does not write the tokens. But the possibility he does, exists.